# how to inject Func<T,U> with Windsor container

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, delegates, castle-windsor

```
 public BranchUOW(Func<FoodieTenantContext,BranchRepository> branchRepository, 
        Func<FoodieTenantContext, BranchContactRepository> branchContactRepository,
        FoodieTenantContext ctx, IMapperService mapperService)
        : base(ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        _branchRepository = branchRepository(ctx);
        _branchContactRepository = branchContactRepository(ctx);
        _mapperService = mapperService;
    }
```

Where BranchRepository looks as

```
 public BranchRepository(FoodieTenantContext ctx)
        : base(ctx)
    {
    }
```

Tried with the below permutations

```
  container.Register(
          Component.For<Func<FoodieTenantContext, BranchRepository>>()
          .ImplementedBy(typeof(IRepository<BranchRepository>))
          .LifestyleTransient()
         );

        container.Register(
           Component.For<Func<FoodieTenantContext, BranchContactRepository>>()
           .ImplementedBy(typeof(IRepository<BranchContactRepository>))
           .LifestyleTransient()
          );
```

But unable to instansitae & throws the below error.

> Type foodie.common.Repository.IRepository`1[[foodie.tenant.EF.Repository.Domain.BranchRepository, foodie.tenant.EF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] is abstract.\r\n As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of service 'foodie.common.Repository.IRepository`1[[foodie.tenant.EF.Repository.Domain.BranchRepository, foodie.tenant.EF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Did you forget to proxy it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<BranchRepository>(),
    Component.For<Func<FoodieTenantContext, BranchRepository>>()
    .Instance(c => container.Resolve<BranchRepository>(new { ctx = c }))
    .LifestyleTransient()
);
```

But I would recommend rather to go for typed factory.

https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md

Comment: Yeah..it solved the problem :) Thankssssssssssssssssss